# On what condition $trace(A) \ge trace(AB)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, positive-semidefinite

Considering $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite real symmetric matrices, on what conditions we can have $trace(A) \ge trace(AB)$?

Comment: What exactly is a PSD matrix?

Comment: Positieve semi-definite

Comment: Do you know if $A,B$ commute? If they don't the problem is much harder, as $AB$ may not be symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Under the extra assumption that $A,B$ commute**: Then $A,B$ are orthogonally diagonalizable simultaneously.

Let $P$ be an orthogonal matrix, and $D_1,D_2$ be diagonal such that 
$$A=PD_1P^T \\
B=PD_2P^{T}$$

Then 
$$AB=PD_1D_2P^{T}$$

Therefore, if $\lambda_1,.., \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\beta_1,.., \beta_n$ are the eigenvalues of $B$, **in any order**, there exists a permutation $\sigma$ such that 
$$\tr(AB)=\lambda_1 \beta_{\sigma(1)}+...+\lambda_n \beta_{\sigma(n)}$$

The question you are asking in this case is basically the following

**Question** Given some non-negative numbers $\lambda_1,.., \lambda_n$  and $\beta_1,.., \beta_n$, (and a permutation $\sigma$ which can actually be ignored by reordering $\beta$) under which condition do we have
$$\lambda_1 \beta_{\sigma(1)}+...+\lambda_n \beta_{\sigma(n)}\leq \lambda_1+..+\lambda_n ?$$

Note that for any such $\lambda, \beta$'s you can take $A,B$ to be the diagonal matrix with those numbers on the diagonal for an example/counterexample.

If $A$ is not the zero matrix, then the most obvious answer is : all eigenvalues of $B$ are $\leq 1$.

**If $A,B$ don't commute**, the question seems to be way to complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer! Unfortunately, A and B don't commute, and I'm going to make more assumptions about their structure, but I think it's better to put it as a new question.

Comment: I changed the problem assumptions as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081016/how-to-choose-b-to-have-traceh-ge-traceb-tophb